# Why ST_Intersection from Postgis returns multilinestring for self-intersecting linestrings?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, intersection

I am trying on PostgreSQL with the extension Postgis to get the geometry of a gps_trace that intersects a box, then i want to get one linestring for each distinct part of the trace in the box. In [the following example with 1 trace and 1 box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLCIQ.png) , that would mean ST_intersection returns me a multilinestring with 2 linestrings inside, so that i can extract each of them with ST_Dump()

The geometries are in epsg 4326, I use the request `SELECT ST_Intersection(gps_traces.geom, grid.box) 
FROM gps_traces, grid`

But as a result, i get a multilestring with 34 geometries inside. After [zooming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxNNM.png) a little, i discovered that when the line self-intersects, it seems to consider and register each part as a separate linestring although at the beginning, the trace was a linestring in one go.

I am extremely surprised of this behavior, and didn't find any documentation on the subject nor topics that talked about it, so i'm asking here how is build the geometry resulting from an intersection and why I get this behavior ?

This is the first time i get to use stackoverflow, so I apologize if some elements are missing

Comment: It seems I ran into the same issue with my AIS position reports (ship positions).

I only want to know when the ship entered the given polygon and when it leaves again.
From the millions of positions I have, I create a daily linestring (linestringm with the timestamp) and store this in the database (requires less space, etc.).
This is later used to check then it intersects with the polygon and I run ST_Dump to get the details from which I finally use the last and first point using ST_InterpolatePoint with my LineString + ST_StartPoint / ST_EndPoint with the ST_Dump result)

Comment: @user3466500 I don't remember how I dealt with it back then, but I am glad you found a solution and posted your method here in case somebody else has the same problem

Comment: It's actually not solved. I was just explaining what I'm doing until I run into the same issue you had.